# asp.net web services(.asmx) authorization for particular method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

I want to create a web service which has 2 methods and should be accessed by 2 clients.
1.  First client should be able to access both the methods.
2.  2nd client should be able to access only one method.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about giving permissions to .asmx file or just a method in .asmx?

Comment: just giving permission to a particular method in .asmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2nd Method add 1 more parameter (authenticationKey) and if key math then return data else show message Invalid key.

```
public string Method2(int ClientId, string authenticationKey)
{
   if(authenticationKey == "CSCdk33792")
   {
     ...
   }
   else
   {
      return "Invalid authenticationKey";
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume the == "CSCdk33792" is just an example to stub some proper security?

Comment: Yes, "CSCdk33792" is just an example key. We can set our key.